# How to express "good teaching skills"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

How can I express that an explanation is clear, considering the intrinsic difficulty of the topic? I mean that the explanation might not be easy to understand, if the subject matter is intrinsically hard, but a superlatively *adjectivy* explanation is one that is as clear as it can get. Someone who frequently produces such explanations could be said to have good teaching skills.
What's a good word to substitute for *adjectivy*?

<sub>*The word that comes to my mind is the French word “pédagogique”, which a dictionary describes as meaning roughly “as coming from a good teacher”. Unfortunately the corresponding English word has negative connotations instead.*</sub>

Comment: What is the English equivalent word that you looked? As far as I know, _pedagogic_ doesn't have a negative connotation.

Comment: If the related word is indeed _pedagogic_ or _pedagogical_, then there is no negative connotation, but I don't think it's what the asker is looking for either. Both words simply mean "related to teaching".

Comment: @sapphiremirage: In fact, you can replace _teaching_ with _pedagogic_ and get a sentence like "they show great pedagogic skills." I don't think there is an English words that means "coming from a good teacher". As for the negative connotation associated with _pedagogue_, both _pedagogue_ and French _pédagogie_ come from a Greek word that was used to denote a slave who accompanied a child to school.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Pedagogue: “One who by teaching has become formal, positive, or pedantic in his ways; (…) a pedant.” (one of the meanings in Webster 1913, which defines *pedagogic* by reference to *pedagogue*). [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pedagogic) (I know, not reliable) gives “haughty and formal” as a meaning. So *pedagogic* looks neutral or negative (whereas the French word is neutral or positive).

Comment: _Pedagogic_: of or relating to teaching; _pedagogue_: a teacher, especially a strict or pedantic one. __[The _New Oxford American Dictionary_.]__

Comment: @kiamlaluno: the French word *pédagogue* was negative until the 19th century (Littré says “se dit le plus souvent en mauvaise part”). But, nowadays, it rather means “someone who is skilled in pedagogy (or teaching)”, just like a physicist is someone who is skilled in physics. So, it is a positive term in modern use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Lucid*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1264676#m_en_us1264676) is an excellent candidate; [*perspicuous*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1277189#m_en_us1277189) is a worthy synonym. Thus:

> - ...but a superlatively *lucid* explanation is one that is as clear as it can get.
> - ...but a superlatively *perspicuous* explanation is one that is as clear as it can get.

Answer (score 4):

*Lucid* and *perspicuous*, as proposed by Jimi, are good matches. If you want to convey the meaning of “convincing” in addition to “teaching”, you can also go with **cogent**.

Comment: +1 for "lucid" and "cogent."  I think cogent is particularly good.

Answer (score 0):

A few words that may or may not inspire:

```
Thorough
Clear
Simple
Complete
Exemplar
Understandable
Layman's
Masterful
Prescient
```